# Running TypeScript files with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, phantomjs

I'm very new to TypeScript but it seems to have certaing benefits over JavaScipt, so I'm eager to try it.

I'm using PhantomJS to, say gather cookies set by a webpage by following the example code.

So I created a `.js` file called `cookies.js` -

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function (status) {
  var cookies = page.cookies;

  console.log('Listing cookies:');
  for(var i in cookies) {
    console.log(cookies[i].name + '=' + cookies[i].value);
  }

  phantom.exit();
});
```

And ran it successfully like `phantomjs cookies.js`

Now I want to convert this into a TypeScript file and then execute it the same way. I found out that if I just rename it to `cookies.ts`, it still works. I have 2 questions-

1. Should I be doing this? I mean I will correct the syntax from JS to TS. I don't see many benefits in this small chunk of code, I'm just doing it out of curiosity.
2. Does PhantomJS support this behavior? (Using `.ts` insted of `.js`)

Comment: No, phantom just imitates a browser. You can use typescript but your code needs to be transpiled to js before phantom can run it.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is a superset of Javascript. It means that any valid JS file is also a valid TS file.

Therefore, you can rename a `.js` file to `.ts` and it will work, but the opposite is not necessarily true. As soon as you start adding Typescript-specific syntax like `let name:string`, renaming the file from `.ts` to `.js` will break it.

PhantomJS is a (headless) browser, and like any browser it can only run Javascript.

You need to transpile Typescript properly to Javascript using a tool like Babel or the `tsc` (TypeScript Compiler) command line.